# May I build my own STM32 dev board?

Tags: pcb, stm32

I wanted to build my own linux dev board. To learn more about PCB design, design rules and how the process works from power to login screen in linux.

I saw that the STM32 chip has free linux IDE for its STM32 MCU's

So the question comes up can and may I?

Comment: You don't need permission, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: That's right. I thought maybe there are licences or something.

Comment: look here https://hackaday.io/project/25678-dil-dev-kits

Answer (score 6):

STM32 parts are microcontrollers, not CPUs. They cannot run a full Linux operating system. (Some of them may be able to run [uClinux](http://www.uclinux.org/), but this is a much more limited operating system, and cannot run the sort of Linux applications you're probably imagining.)

The presence of a Linux IDE for a system does not mean that the system can run Linux. It simply means that it's possible to develop for the system using a Linux host.

Comment: Oke Oke aright. Thanks alot! Do you know which cpu is opensource for full ide linux? I just want to make a dev board and install linux with opensource. I just don't know what or how.

Comment: Ah, now there's a problem: running Linux *on the board* basically requires larger systems like e.g. Freescale iMX53, which require expensive, complicated boards that aren't beginner-friendly.